# Does the excess charge on a $d$ dimensional solid conductor still go to its surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

The title more or less covers it. I thought of this while ago at a talk, and I couldn't get the idea out of my head. Going further, I wonder if there is some sort of solution for the distribution of the surface charge. I think if we restrict ourselves exclusively to hyperspheres, there might be an actual tractable answer out there.

The reason I think this is interesting is because, while the case of $d = 3$ is well-known, as you can see [here](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/64/6/706/1054817/Charge-density-on-a-conducting-needle?redirectedFrom=fulltext), and [here](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/61/12/1084/1054264/The-electrostatics-and-magnetostatics-of-a?redirectedFrom=fulltext), the $d = 1$ and $d = 2$ dimensional cases are not as simple! Furthermore, I think this may be an actual question, as the electric field and charge density are well-defined in $d$ dimensions; see Zwiebach, *A First Course in String Theory*, 2nd ed. In trying to solve this, I derived some interesting results regarding the electric field of a $d$-dimensional hypersphere a distance $r$ from its center, with $r < R$ ($R$ being the radius of the sphere). For the curious, the answer I got is $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) = \rho \mathbf{r}/d$ (Feel free to comment and ask for an explanation of this; the answer is in Heaviside-Lorentz units by the way).

Anyway, any help, insights, or recommended readings would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!